# USPS Tracking Xml

Tags: xml, api, postman, usps

Testing in Postman url is http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=

Request

```
<TrackRequest USERID=”xxxxxxx”>
               <TrackID ID="xxxx">
                             </TrackID>

                      </TrackRequest>
```

response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Number>80040B19</Number>
    <Description>XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed.</Description>
    <Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>
```

What is the Error?

Answer (score 0):

`”` in the first line in your XML looks like non-ASCII.
You should use `"` (0x22) not `”` (0x201d) since they are [different characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Unicode_code_point_table).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my working postman request for the USPS API. Make sure XML is the key and the value is your valid XML.